# is there a maximum gold cap?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 1 there was a soft-cap based in the inventory space[¹](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66908/is-there-a-maximum-gold-cap#comment93915_66908) and Diablo 2 there was a cap based on your level, the maximum gold that you could carry in your hero, and in your chest. *(also in world of warcraft)*

I'm worried because the gold is shared between my account in diablo 3 (different from diablo 2 where you could split in other heroes).

Comment: There was no de-jure gold cap in Diablo 1, but a gold stack took an inventory / floor space and was limited to 5k. It meant that you were de-facto limited to (number of inventory slots + number of floor space in Tristram) * 5000 gold.

Comment: @Oak soft-cap =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody outside of Blizzard knows the specific number yet, but the number is at least 100,000,000,000 as that's the max amount you can list an item at in the auction house.

Source: http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-auction-house-functionality

As with every game, there is a technical limitation, but that depends on how the number is stored. A 32 bit signed integer would put the cap at roughly 2 billion(or 4 billion if unsigned), but since the max bid amount clearly surpasses that, I suspect that they may be storing it as a 64 bit integer, putting the technical cap at 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Of course, Blizzard is free to make it lower than that number, and probably have done so.

Comment: I could bit in the wow for over 250.000 but the cap was that. are you sure about it?

Comment: @MichelAyres I think the difference here is that this is listed on Blizzard's official website(I can't find an official source for WoW limits). I also went in an tested and there's a tooltip that states the list price cap is at 100,000,000,000. I find it highly improbable that Blzzard would allow items to be listed above the gold cap if it were impossible to buy those items.

Comment: Currently, the AH only let's you search for items for sale with a buyout up to 2^31 - 1, or 2,147,483,648.  Might just be a bug in the AH tho.